# MemUsage / CPU Usage of GLPK for optimization models

Tags: python, memory, cpu, pyomo, glpk

I am optimizing 2 pyomo energy models with a solver called GLPK.

When you let solver write its output via: `result = optim.solve(model, tee=True)`

Solver gives an output in cmd as:

```
GLPSOL: GLPK LP/MIP Solver, v4.65
Parameter(s) specified in the command line:
 --write /home/okan/Desktop/urbs-oemof/tmpk76ybo_5.glpk.raw --wglp /home/okan/Desktop/urbs-oemof/tmp8qv9hajy.glpk.glp
 --cpxlp /home/okan/Desktop/urbs-oemof/tmpa9k8e86c.pyomo.lp
Reading problem data from '/home/okan/Desktop/urbs-oemof/tmpa9k8e86c.pyomo.lp'...
1519 rows, 1155 columns, 3894 non-zeros
9618 lines were read
Writing problem data to '/home/okan/Desktop/urbs-oemof/tmp8qv9hajy.glpk.glp'...
7210 lines were written
GLPK Simplex Optimizer, v4.65
1519 rows, 1155 columns, 3894 non-zeros
Preprocessing...
1159 rows, 1011 columns, 2979 non-zeros
Scaling...
 A: min|aij| =  4.705e-03  max|aij| =  7.964e+02  ratio =  1.693e+05
GM: min|aij| =  4.065e-01  max|aij| =  2.460e+00  ratio =  6.052e+00
EQ: min|aij| =  1.652e-01  max|aij| =  1.000e+00  ratio =  6.052e+00
Constructing initial basis...
Size of triangular part is 1156
      0: obj =   1.914903944e+07 inf =   8.143e+06 (60)
     68: obj =   7.130756139e+10 inf =   0.000e+00 (0)
*   266: obj =   2.358801019e+10 inf =   1.920e-10 (0) 1
OPTIMAL LP SOLUTION FOUND
Time used:   0.0 secs
Memory used: 1.6 Mb (1728515 bytes)
Writing basic solution to '/home/okan/Desktop/urbs-oemof/tmpk76ybo_5.glpk.raw'...
2683 lines were written
```

I would like to compare the `Memory used` and `Time used` of GLPK from both models. How would I get this `Memory used` and `Time used` as float values in python? Is there a way? or what else could you offer me, eventually does the same thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1:

```
result = optim.solve(model, logfile='log.txt', tee=False)
```

Step 2,3 and 4:

```
with open('log.txt', 'r') as log:
    mem = log.read().replace('\n', ' ')
    mem = float(mem[mem.find('Memory used:')+12:
                    mem.find('Mb')])
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a more direct way, but this is how I retrieve infos from solver logs.:

1. Solve the problem while saving the solver log file at a place that you will be able to get later.

   ```
   results = opt.solve(model, logfile='MySolverLogFile.txt')
   ```
2. Open log file with python file reader and retrieve the whole file as a string.
3. Search within the string for your keyword. Make sure you make a very strict search. That means, if your memory usage is given like `"Memory used: "`, don't only search for `"Memory"`, search for the whole word, including the double dots and the space to avoid getting wrong occurences.
4. Make the value found after the text "Memory used: " the amount of used memory by storing it into a variable.

You will be able to retrieve many other informations if you code it so that it accepts  other keywords. But if you change solver, you will have to change the way you retrieve these informations from your solver log.

Comment: well that is what I thought, write the log to text file and then string search. But the problem with this is kinda not the best solution. It would be better if there is a glpk command which lets me get this Memory used value via something like: `mem = opt.memory_used(model)`

Comment: code at least the 2nd, 3rd and 4th items then I can accept this as a answer